# Save faces in Separate images with android Face Detection

Tags: android, face-detection

I need to **detect** **faces** in captured image and save the detected faces in **separate images**. So far i am able to **detect faces** but how can i save detected faces in **separate images**?

Comment: You'd have to convert a bitmap to an array of pixels with x,y coordinates and from that array you should be able to grab a rectangle's worth of values?

Comment: Thanks  @user3427079 for your help... I have done it..

Comment: Hi! I have to face same challenge. Can you help me with d code.

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/darwinfrancis/viola library to get cropped faces from bitmap image